# Database natural join and renaming

Tags: database, rename, relational-algebra, renaming, natural-join

I am trying to learn relational algebra and database query. In the following question and model answer, if we rename every attribute in Q1, as in the answer, can the natural join still be performed?   I thought the two relations need to have at least one common attribute with the same name. Could you help to explain what's happening here? Many thanks! 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute names don't have to be the same, but it can be confusing when they aren't. However, by mentioning e.g. [sid] < SUPPLIERS[sid] you make plain the actual relationship.

This you could rename e.g. Suppliers.sid to Suppliers.supplierId and then make plain that Catalog.sid relates to Suppliers.supplierId and it's all there.

In practice, I always call the PK of tables I design Id, and when use it in other tables as an FK, I call it [tablename]Id, e.g. SupplierId.

Comment: Thank you. You mean if the attributes in the two tables do not have any same names, natural join can still be performed. For example the resulting table after nature join will have the attributes "sid, sid', pid, pid', cost, cost'" ?

Comment: I do mean that the names don't have to be the same for the join to work. I'm not sure what your last sentence means.

Comment: I meant to ask, what would be the result after joining  "sid, pid, cost" and "sid', pid', cost'"?  Is the result a table with attributes sid, sid', pid, pid', cost, cost' ?

Comment: This will vary by database type. In SQL Server duplicate column names in a query are not allowed; if you don't give names by select a.sid as asid, b.sid as bsid...etc then it will give sid, sid2, pid, pid2 and so on. What MYSql and others do I don't know.